# How do you calculate cohen's L so that you can plug it into a power calculation for multiple linear regression?

Tags: regression, linear, statistical-power, cohens-d

I am reviewing a book called Statistical Methods for Healthcare Research so I can learn how to do a power calculation for my sample size for multiple linear regression.

This book says that cohen provides the following formula: $N = L(1-R^2)/R^2 + u + 1$. It says that $L$ can be obtained from a table and it is defined by Cohen as a function of power and number of independent variables at a given $\alpha$-level.

I have looked in Cohen's 1988 book (the only one I have access to) and cannot find how to do this.

Does anyone know where I can obtain the value of $L$ for $4$ independent variables with a power of $80\%$ and an $\alpha$ of $0.05$?